# python pip install -f switch is ignoring the directory I provide

Tags: python, pip, package

Note: Using a Win 10 machine.
I created a virtual environment, and have activated it.
The machine is connected to the Internet, BUT I'm developing procedures for machines that do not have easy connection to the Internet, so the general procedures have to work for those machines as well.

First thing after activating the virtual environment I want to upgrade pip (for the version of python I'm using).

I am in directory 'mydir'
The subdirectory mydir\packages I have (among other files) pip-20.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
I execute:

```
python -m pip install pip-20.2.3-py3-none-any.whl -f ./packages --no-index
```

But this gives me the error

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\mydir\pip-20.2.3-py3-none-any.whl'

Meaning it ignored the -f ./packages.
I also tried -f packages and -f .\packages .
What am I missing?

Comment: It should be `python -m pip install pip -f ./packages --no-index`. Either you specify dist name _and_ links source, or you specify the path to wheel without the link source.

Comment: BTW you'll probably need `--upgrade`, too.

Comment: Right on both counts! python -m pip install -U pip -f packages --no-index worked! tx, elb